# Get the reason app moved to inactive state

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, lifecycle

I'd like to know why application is become inactive.
I have

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onApplicationWillResignActive(notification:), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
```

and I get the event, but I'd like to know what cause my app to become inactive. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is running in foreground and doesn't receive any events this is the inactive state when a call comes or a message

If the app is running in background and doesn't execute any code this is the suspended state

Answer (score 0):

Apple says:

> The app is running in the foreground but is not receiving events. This
>   might happen as a result of an interruption or because the app is
>   transitioning to or from the background.

The `inactive` state is just temporary, it could happen if the user is receiving a phone call before accept it or while transitioning to background.

I think [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/07/handling-ios-app-states-state-machine/) flow chart explains pretty well all the states.

Comment: I specifically asked that I want to know the Reason my app moved to inactive state ( it may be home button, phone call, notification center call etc.) I do want to know these reasons